# GWT Scrollable Datagrid in tablets

Tags: java, gwt, tablet

Ok so it's a bit of a long shot here, but here's the issue :

We have a GWT Application that works fine on browsers, however our buttons which are located in a datagrid column were not responsive sometime on some tablets.

I've tracked down the issue to this :

Buttons work as long as the datagrid fits in the screen, but as soon as it becomes scrollable, it would seem that the "scroll panel" is absorbing all the inputs and the click event never reaches the button.

I'm guessing it might be because those tablets are handling the scroll as a "make the full panel scrollable by finger swiping" while the browsers are displaying the scrollbar on the right, which doesn't cover the panel.

It's a very very specific problem, but if anyone ever encountered it, some help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you attach a click handler to each button, or detect a click on a column?

Comment: Button has the buttoncell behavior, which means that the column has a FieldUpdater and the button calls the valueupdater.update() on click in it's onBrowserEvent method. I've tried multiple tests already and the click actually never reaches the button in a scrollable panel on the tablet. Tried it with a standard buttoncell aswell, same issue, so it's not my specific buttoncell implementation that is faulty.

Comment: Try to add addCellPreviewHandler() to your DataGrid. Check what native events it catches when you try to click on a button: GWT.log("Native event: " + event.getNativeEvent().getType()); You can limit it to the column with buttons (event.getColumn() == myTable.getColumnIndex(myButtonColumn));

Comment: There's no event going in there aswell, on browsers I'm receiving the correct sequence for a click (mouseover / mousedown / focus / click / blur), on the tablet output is empty. I've overrided onBrowserEvent2 on my datagrid also to check for all the click events, and when I press a button, there's a click registered but on the browser it's targetting the ButtonObject as it should, on the tablet the target is a DivElement, and I haven't found a way to know more yet since I can't use devmode on tablet, I can only compile and execute which gives me much less debug tools.

Comment: Can you catch events for other columns, or no events are registered anywhere in the DataGrid?

Comment: There are no click events at all registered in addCellPreviewHandler() on my tablet, no matter where I click in the table :/

Comment: Which browser you use? What OS?

Comment: Test desktop browsers are Chrome 23, Firefox 16 and IE9, all Windows, it works fine in all those.

We have several tablets in our testing, this particular problem is ocurring on an the Asus Transformer in Android 4.0.3, stock browser app.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please, file a report at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list

Comment: Done, if anyone ever lands here regarding this problem, have a look here, maybe there will be you answer there one day : http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7832